# template forms in prismic

Tags: prismic.io

I'm new to prismic and trying to figure out if this is right tool for what I need. I need to create multiple form templates. I want prismic user to be able to build out the template, which will get loaded into gatsby where each field will get built out as components based on a title, type, action, name.

- Title will be the title or label.
- type will be the type of form element, ex: input, button, radio action,
- if its a button the action it needs to do.
- name the name for the form element.

Does prismic seem like a good candidate for this and does anyone know of any examples of how I might go about setting up the prismic end. Most of what Ive seen so far is full pages with just title and images. Not exactly forms.

In their repository I only see these options to create elements am I missing some important ones ?

- Title
- Rich Text
- Image
- Content Relationship
- Link
- Link to Media
- Date
- Timestamp
- color
- number
- key text
- Select
- Embed
- GeoPoint
- Group

How would I go about creating form elements, Is there a way to create custom objects to export? Every time I try to add a new filed or a custom object to the json editor it says. Unrecognized, property it will be ignored. 
I'd like to be able to use the group to group a bunch of form elements together even if they are just custom objects that I can pass custom properties to so when I load the group into React I can use the custom properties to build out my components ?? Can anyone set me straight here on if this is possible using prismic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say if Prismic is the best tool for this particular job, but i think you're overestimating what exactly you need in order to render a html form.

Consider the following custom type. It really only consists of titles, structured texts, a repeatable zone and a select. What you do with that data is completely up to you on the front end.

```js
{
  "Main": {
    "uid": {
      "type": "UID",
      "config": {
        "label": "Form UID",
        "placeholder": "Form UID"
      }
    },
    "form_title": {
      "type": "StructuredText",
      "config": {
        "single": "heading2",
        "label": "Form Title",
        "placeholder": "Form Title"
      }
    },
    "action_title": {
      "type": "StructuredText",
      "config": {
        "single": "heading2",
        "label": "action title",
        "placeholder": "Submit form"
      }
    },
    "form_action_description": {
      "type": "StructuredText",
      "config": {
        "single": "paragraph",
        "label": "form action description",
        "placeholder": "form action description"
      }
    },
    "success_message": {
      "type": "StructuredText",
      "config": {
        "single": "paragraph",
        "label": "success message",
        "placeholder": "success message"
      }
    },
    "error_message": {
      "type": "StructuredText",
      "config": {
        "single": "paragraph",
        "label": "error message",
        "placeholder": "error message"
      }
    },
    "submit_button_text": {
      "type": "StructuredText",
      "config": {
        "single": "paragraph",
        "label": "submit button text",
        "placeholder": "submit"
      }
    },
    "body": {
      "type": "Slices",
      "fieldset": "Slice zone",
      "config": {
        "choices": {
          "test": {
            "type": "Slice",
            "fieldset": "Form Section",
            "description": "Section of a form",
            "icon": "vertical_align_center",
            "display": "list",
            "non-repeat": {
              "form_section_title": {
                "type": "StructuredText",
                "config": {
                  "single": "heading1",
                  "label": "Form Section title",
                  "placeholder": "Form Section title"
                }
              },
              "form_section_description": {
                "type": "StructuredText",
                "config": {
                  "single": "paragraph",
                  "label": "Form Section Description",
                  "placeholder": "Form Section Description"
                }
              }
            },
            "repeat": {
              "label": {
                "type": "StructuredText",
                "config": {
                  "single": "paragraph",
                  "label": "label",
                  "placeholder": "label"
                }
              },
              "type": {
                "type": "Select",
                "config": {
                  "options": [
                    "text",
                    "textarea",
                    "checkbox",
                    "radio",
                    "submit"
                  ],
                  "default_value": "text",
                  "label": "type"
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "StructuredText",
                "config": {
                  "single": "paragraph",
                  "label": "name",
                  "placeholder": "name"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```